# VBA Excel - Create pie chart from 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, graph

I am trying to create a chart from calculated values in a procedure
The first part of the procedure creates an Array (Variant) called "varUnique"

Let says for example it has the following values:

```
varUnique(0,1)="Houses"
varUnique(0,2)="Buildings"
varUnique(0,3)="Parkings"
varUnique(1,1)=4
varUnique(1,2)=3
varUnique(1,3)=9
```

I would like to create a new graph sheet that shows the previous

My code:

```
Set new_chart = Charts.Add()
    With new_chart
        .ChartType = xlPie
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = varUnique(0)
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = varUnique(1)
    End With
```

generates a runtime error '9' : subscript out of range at the .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = varUnique(0) step

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: varUnique is 2D, should I split into 2 1D arrays ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Index`. Note that `Index` is one-based.

```
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Application.Index(varUnique, 1)
.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Application.Index(varUnique, 2)
```

Output:

[image]